# Does cloth-covered wiring inside flex conduit need to be replaced when I replace a fixture?

Tags: wiring

The pull chain on an old Allied Mouled incandescent lamp holder broke. Do I need to have an electrician replace what I think is rubberized cloth covered wiring before installing a new Leviton lampholder?

[image: h]

Comment: Where are you located? There are places where only electricians are allowed to touch wiring. In most places, minor adjustments like replacing a light fixture (especially with same/similar model) doesn't require a professional or significant rework in your situation.

Comment: Also if you own a single family detached house or not rent.  Rentals usually need electricians.  With the breaker off, if you can play with the wire insulation and it does not fall/break off, you should be be able to just wire the new light in.

Comment: Or this? [Is 100-year old armored (BX) cable a safety hazard and should it be replaced?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198103/is-100-year-old-armored-bx-cable-a-safety-hazard-and-should-it-be-replaced)

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine. Just use some black or white (to match the wire insulation) tape if there are any bits of insulation coming off.